# Loading zipped python module from database

Tags: python, module, python-2.7

I have a Python module with a structure like this:

```
demo/
├── __init__.py
├── app.py
├── models.py
├── modules.py
```

Now I want to zip this module and store it into a database.

How would I load a structured package like this?
While I have no issue loading a single `.py` file and use its functions I don't know how to deal with a package. In this case `app.py` imports from `models.py` and `modules.py`.

When using this approach it loads `app.py` first and throws and exception because it has not loaded the other 2 files.

```
import new
code = <the code from the db>
mod = new.module('foo')
exec code in mod.__dict__
sys.modules['foo'] = mod
```

How is this done right?

Comment: Do you actually have a ZIP file? You may want to look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipimport.html#module-zipimport

Comment: yes but it comes from a database so there is no path associated with it.

Comment: Retrieve the file from the DB, store it somewhere somehow, then add the location to `sys.path` and import it?

Comment: @JonClements yes that would work but my filesystem is read only.

Comment: Guess you'll have to write your own import handler then... The only other option I can think of is if you created a small ramfs that could be used...

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are looking for is creating finder and loader classes, described by Doug Hellmann in one of is PyMOTW posts:

http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/sys/imports.html

Although Doug's full post is probably required reading, the meat of an example for storing and loading a mult-file module from a database is in the section using the Python database "shelve":

http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/sys/imports.html#importing-from-a-shelve

Comment: This is not very helpful, could you give more details?

Comment: It's not a trivial thing to do.  Doug's post is quite long, but if you read through it, you will see that Doug shows how to store a set of module files in a database - in particular the built-in "shelve" database, and then load the modules from the database later.

Comment: Although this doesn't follow SO guidelines since it simply links other information, it explains why (it's complicated).  So +1.  It will be a problem if doughellman ever misses a DNS registry payment.

Comment: It already happened, PyMOTW now is redone for python3.  The older link is now http://pymotw.com/2/sys/imports.html